# $\frac{d}{dS} \int_{-\infty}^{d_1(S)} e^{-u^2/2} du = ?$

Tags: derivatives

$\displaystyle{\frac{d}{dS} \int_{-\infty}^{d_1(S)} e^{-u^2/2} du}$

Would the above equate to $e^{-d_1^2/2} \frac{d(d_1)}{dS}$? Why do we include the derivative of the bound?

I suppose this is closely linked to the fundamental theorem of calculus, and in my case it is extremely rusty (non-existent practically).

EDIT:

From Black-Scholes: $d_1 = \frac{\ln(S/E)+(r-D+\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2)(T-t)}{\sigma \sqrt{T-t}}$. All are constants, but $S$.

Comment: Is $d_1$ some generic function of $S$, or does it have a concrete expression? Do we know at least a lower bound for it?

Comment: I will edit the question. Second please

Comment: Do we also know anything about the domain of $S$?

Comment: $S$ is strictly positive

Comment: Actually not strictly, not that it matters now. But it is quite rare that it would be zero. $S$ is the price of the underlying stock on which the option price is calculated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your result is correct, but there's a minor technicality as you are going to see.

Let's try a slightly more general version of your question: how to compute $\dfrac {\Bbb d} {\Bbb d t} \int \limits _{f(t)} ^{g(t)} F(x) \Bbb d x$, where $f$ and $g$ are derivable functions? There is a theorem (a consequence of the fundamental theorem of calculus, as you suspected) telling us that this is $F(g(t)) g'(t) - F(f(t)) f'(t)$. The trouble is that $-\infty$ is not the value of a derivable function, so we'll have to avoid it using some trick. Note that, in general, $\int \limits _a ^b = \int \limits _a ^c + \int \limits _c ^b$, and this is valid for just any $c$, not just for $c \in (a,b)$. Therefore, write your function as $\int \limits _{-\infty} ^0 + \int \limits _0 ^{d_1 (S)}$ (instead of $0$ you could have chosen any other point on $\Bbb R$, it wouldn't have made any difference as you are going to see). The first integral will be a constant number, which will vanish under derivation. You may now use the above formula with $f=0$ and $g = d_1$ (and $t = S$), to get the result: $\Bbb e ^{-\frac {d_1 (S) ^2} 2} \dfrac {\Bbb d d_1} {\Bbb d S}$.

Comment: Thank you so much! Very simple explanation, I need to start slowly studying mathematical analysis.