# $\frac{\partial}{\partial S}\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{d_1}e^{-\frac{1}{2}\phi^2}d\phi = ?$

Tags: derivatives, partial-derivative

I have previously asked a similar question: [$\frac{d}{dS} \int_{-\infty}^{d_1(S)} e^{-u^2/2} du = ?$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1551793/fracdds-int-inftyd-1s-e-u2-2-du)

$\frac{\partial}{\partial S}\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{d_1}e^{-\frac{1}{2}\phi^2}d\phi = e^{-\frac{1}{2}d_1^2}\frac{\partial d_1}{\partial S}$ according to what I have learned from that question.

I do not appear to understand my notes fully however. So $N(d_1) = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{d_1}e^{-\frac{1}{2}\phi^2}d\phi$, and basically they show that $\frac{\partial N(d_1)}{\partial S} = \frac{d N(d_1)}{dd1} \frac{\partial d_1}{\partial S}$ and I am not quite sure what the $\frac{d N(d_1)}{dd1}$ evaluates to, but from what I can deduce it should be $d_1 \frac{e^{-\frac{1}{2}d_1^2}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}$, is that so? And if it so, then why do we have $d_1$ there, that is my main question? And if it is not, I will have to add a bit more detail to the question. I have a feeling my deduction might not be correct.

EDIT:

$$d_1 = \frac{\log (S/E) + (r+\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2 (T-t))}{\sigma \sqrt{T-t}}$$

Answer (score 1):

With slightly more suggestive notation. Define
$$ f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}, \ f(x) = \frac{e^{- \frac{x^2}{2}}}{2 \pi}$$
and 
$$ F : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}, \ F(x) = \int_0^x f(t) \ dt$$
By definition $F$ is now the integral function of $f$ and hence we have $F'(x) = f(x)$. Now in particular for some other variable $S$ we have
$$ \frac{\partial F}{\partial S} = \frac{\partial F}{\partial x} \frac{\partial x}{\partial S} = F'(x) \frac{\partial x}{\partial S} = \frac{e^{- \frac{x^2}{2}}}{2 \pi} \frac{\partial x}{\partial S}$$
Now by the definition of $x$ (this is $d_1$) in your question we have
$$ \frac{\partial x}{\partial S} = \frac{1}{\sigma S \sqrt{T - t}}$$
Note that even though $x$ might be a function of more variables than just $S$ because we are taking partial derivatives we treat the other variables as if they were constant. Combining the above we have
$$ \frac{\partial F}{\partial S} = \frac{e^{- \frac{x^2}{2}}}{2 \pi} \frac{1}{\sigma S \sqrt{T - t}}$$
Plugging in the equation for $x$ gives you the final result.

Comment: I have added the definition of $d_1$